# WebSocket connection failed:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am dealing with an error that says the web socket connection failed in my MERN web app.
here is my server site code:

```
    const http = require('http')
    const { Server } = require("socket.io");
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());

    let server = http.createServer(app)

    const io = new Server(server, {
      cors: {
        origin: `${process.env.MYBIYESADI}`
      },
      allowEIO3: true
    })
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("a user connected.")
   socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("a user disconnected!")
        io.emit("onlineUsers", users)
    })
  })
```

and frontend site code is:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = useRef()
useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`, { transports: ["websocket"] })
  }, [])
```

What's not written as expected?
***Its working fine locally and I have hosted both in wss and https as in URL but after hosting to aws docker it shows that wss connection failed as***

> 2.647cd368.chunk.js:2
> WebSocket connection to 'wss://url/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Comment: You can follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808580/establish-web-socket-communication-with-react-and-express-nginx-docker#) Hope it helps